# How do I remove the messy lines in this plotly funnel and generally make it more clear and attractive?

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, visualization

[Plotly chart with messy lines and illegible percentages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tp9k.png)

I've tried editing the width and color of the lines but 'none' returns errors.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

marketing_funnel_count = marketing_funnel_count.sort_values('FUNNEL_EVENT_COUNT', ascending=False)

# Calculate the percent change by level
marketing_funnel_count['Percent Change'] = [100.0] + [(marketing_funnel_count['FUNNEL_EVENT_COUNT'][i] / marketing_funnel_count['FUNNEL_EVENT_COUNT'][i-1]) * 100 for i in range(1, len(marketing_funnel_count))]

# Create the funnel chart
fig = go.Figure(go.Funnel(
    y=marketing_funnel_count['FUNNEL_EVENT'],
    x=marketing_funnel_count['FUNNEL_EVENT_COUNT'],
    textposition='inside',
    textinfo='value+percent previous',
    marker=dict(color=['#FFD700', '#C0C0C0', '#CD7F32', '#800000', '#FFD700', '#C0C0C0']),
    connector=dict(line_color='rgba(0,0,0,0)', line_width=0.1),
    showlegend=False))

# Add the percent change annotations
for i in range(len(marketing_funnel_count)):
    fig.add_annotation(x=marketing_funnel_count['FUNNEL_EVENT_COUNT'][i], y=marketing_funnel_count['FUNNEL_EVENT'][i],
                       text=f'{marketing_funnel_count["Percent Change"][i]:.1f}%',
                       showarrow=False)

# Show the chart
fig.show()
```

Comment: hello and welcome to stackoverflow! can you include the code you used to make this figure in your question? also when you say you've `"tried editing the width and color of the lines but 'none' returns errors"` can you show that code as well as the error message? it's much easier for people to help you if we can reproduce the figure and errors you're getting - thanks!

Comment: Just added the code. The lines connecting it are messy and I want them removed.

Comment: thanks for adding the code – this clears a lot of things up! can you also provide a small sample of `marketing_funnel_count`? we need this at a minimum to reproduce your figure. you can copy and paste the output from `marketing_funnel_count.head().to_dict()` to your question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may need to set the `visible=False` option in the `connector` argument in `go.Funnel` to hide these lines:  https://plotly.com/python/reference/funnel/#funnel-connector

Comment: Now I'm wondering how to clean up the insides of the funnel, I don't know what those weird scribbles are.

Comment: @Kate you might consider asking that as a separate question if it's different enough from your original question

Comment: Done! See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75583102/how-to-get-rid-of-these-weird-scribbles-in-plotly