# How to get rid of these weird scribbles in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

See the code below, I've messed around with the font, inside/outside, and other formatting options and haven't had any luck. I'm not even sure what these weird scribbles are

[image: Plotly chart]

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

marketing_funnel_count = marketing_funnel_count.sort_values('FUNNEL_EVENT_COUNT', ascending=False)

# Calculate the percent change by level
marketing_funnel_count['Percent Change'] = [100.0] + [(marketing_funnel_count['FUNNEL_EVENT_COUNT'][i] / marketing_funnel_count['FUNNEL_EVENT_COUNT'][i-1]) * 100 for i in range(1, len(marketing_funnel_count))]

# Create the funnel chart
fig = go.Figure(go.Funnel(
    y=marketing_funnel_count['FUNNEL_EVENT'],
    x=marketing_funnel_count['FUNNEL_EVENT_COUNT'],
    textposition='inside',
    textinfo='percent previous',
    marker=dict(color=['#FFD700', '#C0C0C0', '#CD7F32', '#800000', '#FFD700', '#C0C0C0']),
    connector=dict(line_color='rgba(0,0,0,0)', line_width=0.1),
    connector_visible=False,
    showlegend=False))

# Add the percent change annotations
for i in range(len(marketing_funnel_count)):
    fig.add_annotation(x=marketing_funnel_count['FUNNEL_EVENT_COUNT'][i], y=marketing_funnel_count['FUNNEL_EVENT'][i],
                       text=f'{marketing_funnel_count["Percent Change"][i]:.1f}%',
                       showarrow=False)

# Show the chart
fig.show()
```

Comment: Just added the plotly chart, don't know why that was removed to begin with

Comment: No, that was an answer to another problem and I was told to ask a different question. Thanks!